# crontab job to open terminal and run command in new terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, cron

I'm using crontab to schedule python script but I want to open new terminal and run the command in it so I can interact with the terminal.

The script involves browser automation, so I need to manually solve captcha and press Enter to let the script continue. That's why I want to have the script running in a new terminal that I can see and interact with.

I am new to ubuntu so if there's any alternative to crontab please do suggest if it's not possible using crontab.

Here's what I tried

```
24 11 * * 1-5 gnome-terminal && bash /home/user/UpdatedScrapers/scheduler/run_growth_ai.sh
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `gnome-terminal --execute bash /home/user/UpdatedScrapers/scheduler/run_growth_ai.sh` which will open GNOME Terminal and run that script within